# Scrapy recursive website crawl after login

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, scrapy, scraper

I had coded a spider to crawl website after login

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "login"
    allowed_domains = ["mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://login.mydomain.com/login']

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]'), restrict_xpaths=('//a[contains(text(), "Previous")]',)), 'parse_info')]

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={"username":"myemail","password":"mypassword"},
            callback=self.parse_info, dont_filter=True)]

    def parse_info(self, response):
        items = []
        for tr in range(1, 5):
            xpath = "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[1]/text()" % tr
            td1 = Selector(response=response).xpath(xpath).extract()
            item = MyItem()
            item['col1'] = td1
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

And the html

```
<html>
   <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   <div><a href="?page=2">Next</a></div>
   <div><a href="#">Previous</a></div>
</html>
```

So what the spider does is it automatically login the user from the login page and redirect to the home page with the html above.

Now what I want to achieve is that I want to scrape the next page after the first page using the python script above.

I have read about the Scrapy documentation about Rules implementation but I have no success to make it work. Please help me out I'm stuck on this for over a day now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read about the Scrapy documentation about Rules implementation
>   but I have no success to make it work.

The Rule in your code does not work because you are using the standard Spider (`scrapy.Spider`) and not the `CrawlSpider`.

Keep the standard Spider and implement the pagination manually instead of using the CrawlSpider. Do something like:

```
def parse_info(self, response):
    # items = []
    for tr in range(1, 5):
        xpath = "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[1]/text()" % tr
        td1 = Selector(response=response).xpath(xpath).extract()
        item = MyItem()
        item['col1'] = td1
        # items.append(item)
        yield item
    # return items

    # If there is a next page, extract href, build request
    # and send it to server
    next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href')
    if next_page:
        next_page_href = next_page.extract()[0]
        next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_href)
        request = scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse_info)
        yield request
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, now I'm getting this error when I follow your script after I run the scraper: `SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator`

Comment: Please try to use `yield item` instead of building a list and returning that. I edited my answer with those changes.

Comment: Great! You just saved my day. Thanks :)